# unknown column in where clause codeigniter when deleting record

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a simple query to delete record from mysql database.

Here is my query:

```
$this->db->where('post_Id', $post_Id);
$result = $this->db->delete($this->mastables['post'],$post_Id);

return $result;
```

This is what I'm getting:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column
>   '108' in 'where clause' DELETE FROM `tbl_post` WHERE `post_Id` = 
>   '108' AND `108` IS NULL
>
> Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\socialsite\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line
>   Number: 330

Comment: Whats this `$this->mastables['post']` I think should be link this `$this->db->delete('post',$post_Id);` and why are you returning a delete?

Comment: I'm using db config to remove prefixes from table names...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508590/what-is-a-table-prefix

Comment: Not understand what meaning

Comment: eg: table name with prefix tbl_post and I'm using it as post. Thats what I did using "mastables['post']". btw you have to have db config php in the config folder to point table names with prefixes.

Comment: Still should not use a return on delete.

Comment: yes. I removed it. But still i'm getting the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70838/discussion-between-nishan-and-mustang83).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the bug
In this code there are 2 values passing to delete. So removing $post_Id in $result will work.

```
$this->db->where('post_Id', $post_Id);
$result = $this->db->delete($this->mastables['post'],$post_Id);
```

Updated code:

```
$this->db->where('post_Id', $post_Id);
$result = $this->db->delete($this->mastables['post']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,it will help and there is no need to return something.

```
function delete($your_id)
{
    $this->db->where('your_tb_id',$your_id); //your_tb_id is key field in your table
    $this->db->delete('table_name');
}
```

Comment: I changed my code to this. this is what I get "Deletes are not allowed unless they contain a "where" or "like" clause"