# Add custom table name like default table name in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress project, I have a table named products, in that for selecting all rows in the product table as of now I have used

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "products";
$output = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name");
```

so now my question is instead of writing the table name with prefix, how can I use like this, `wpdb->posts` in that posts will refer to the table named posts in WordPress table

Comment: If you want to retrieve or query posts (default wordpress posts) you can use function get_posts(). More info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$table_name = "products";
$output = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name");
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply , in my code my table name is tb_test_products not products , and i print your query also i display products like this SELECT * FROM products

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily fixed by replacing the `wp_` string with actual properties provided by using the prefix.

For example, assuming that the table prefix is `wp_`:

- `$wpdb->posts` will correspond to `wp_posts` table
- `$wpdb->postmeta` will correspond to `wp_postmeta` table
- `$wpdb->users` will correspond to `wp_users` table

For more please visit this link.
[Reference URL link](https://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-databases-in-wordpress/)

**Note:** If you create a custom table without prefix then you do not need to use `$wpdb` class. It is just used to get WordPress database default prefix or for `wp_query` AND for others queries.

If you want to run more than one WordPress in a single database then provide prefix otherwise you can skip it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but what i need is how we use $wpdb->posts just like i would like to use $wpdb->products , for that in which file i have to change , because i am new to word-press.can you please help me

Comment: Yes, you can do it. remove the prefix from the table. see this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508590/what-is-a-table-prefix

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```html
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "products";
$output = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name");
```